# What is an enviromental Variable in Operating System Vs IDE's?

Tags: ide, operating-system, global-variables

I'm getting confused of how to place an environmental variable in my head.  So it's like a global variable for the operating system?  So a global for an IDE is just a reference for something the IDE needs to be able to allocate.  Is this the correct idea to have?

Answer (score 0):

At execution each process has an image. It consists of a set of variables in memory that can be accessed, read and modified at all time. It defines the state of a process at a certain point in time.

Some of these variables are created by the process itself for its internal logic, and others will be inherited from its parent process (usually the shell that's used to launch it). They usually describe a certain state of the system. They are called the environment variables. You can use them to define stuff like:
- location of certain executables on your computers (like java or python).
- location of some shared libraries (or DLL if you're on Windows).
- location of the database you're querying
- permission and user access (although that's not the safest place to define it).

The point is, you can define anything in your environment, and every process launched with this environment will inherit from these variables.

I don't know what you mean with the IDE, and quite frankly am not sure I completely understood your question. But since it's been a while and no one answered, I'm hoping it could help you get a beginning of an answer.